# Simple IF statement in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, if-statement

I need help with the `if` statement.The syntax seems to be correct and have verified within this forum as well but not sure why is it going inside the "invalid IF statement".

```
ips=['20.34.178.250']
for index, item in enumerate(ips):
    flag1 = 0
    host_bytes= item.split('.')
    print item,index
    for index1, item1 in enumerate(host_bytes):
        print item1
        if [item1 > 255 and flag1==0]:
            print "IP Address is invalid",item1,flag1
            flag1=1
print flag1
```

Output :

```
20.34.178.250 0
20
IP Address is invalid 20 0
34
IP Address is invalid 34 1
178
IP Address is invalid 178 1
250
IP Address is invalid 250 1
1
```

Comment: `if [item1 > 255 and flag1==0]` is a typo

Comment: You don't need the [] brackets

Comment: Could be simplified with `if any(int(x) > 255 for x in item.split('.'))`

Comment: @cricket_007 You can even use string comparison `x > "255"` without conversion to integer.

Comment: @Rahul This is not a forum, it is a Q&A site. You should also consider using more modern Python 3 syntax e.g. by including `from __future__ import print_function` in your programs and then using `print("somestring")` instead of the old style `print "somestring"`

Answer (score 2):

```
if [item1 > 255 and flag1==0]:
```

your condition creates a 1-element `list` containing `True` or `False`, which is seen as "truthy" since the list isn't empty, so condition is always `True`. You mean:

```
if (item1 > 255 and flag1==0):
```

but in python you don't need the parentheses so save some bytes and risk of typos:

```
if item1 > 255 and flag1==0:
```

Comment: Save some more bytes by making flag1 a proper bool

Comment: @cricket_007 if you are suggesting making `... and not flag1` it may not a proper way to make a bool since it is also validated as False when `flag1` is `Non` and this can be a special case indicating for example that an error has occurred.